# Embedding a piece of html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, embed

Say i create a page in html for a group project. The page contains several fields that would be used for say, reserving a cabin. A user needs to fill these fields across a few overlays that appear one at a time.

My goal is to distribute the work needed for creating these overlays across a few different programmers(we're all students) and embed what they've made into the main piece of html. **This works for html, but can all the embedded html's have their own head tag with their own .js inside?** I found some info on several head tags being a bad practice, and this is what we'd essentially be doing with this route, if it would even work.

The simplest solution i can think of would be to just import the .js we need at the main html page, but thought i'd ask if a more creative way that i don't know how to google exists.

Comment: Have ONE js you all import and remove the import from the snippets when putting them together

Comment: That would definitely do it, and is probably what we'll end up doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every overlay is an html page with its own js, you could use `<iframe>`. It basically displays the entire html page within a frame.

Comment: Just need to make sure all the content for the `<iframe>` is coming from the same domain, or you'll get hit with CORS, which is a browser security feature that prevents external resources being called from a script.

Comment: Does the css of the mainpage affect the contents of the iframe? Or would i need several .css files for this?
This wouldn't necessarily be a problem at all, but useful even. And can i refer to iframe content with jQuery as if it was on the same page to begin with?

Comment: The iFrame will need its own css. If you ajax into a div, not

Comment: `<iframe>` is like a simulation environment, an entire webpage inside a frame so you'll need to specify a js and a css file. I don't know how you made the css but you could maybe use it in each overlay html page ?

Comment: You can acces the iframe content using the `contentWindow.document` property of the frame